# How to silence `unexpected invalid pattern running all tests instead` Warning when overriding CRA Jest config?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

Whenever I use `yarn test` in my [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/) based React app, I encounter a long ***invalid test pattern warning*** before my tests run. Those tests run well but that awkward warning is not that convenient. Here are two concerns I have:

- Is there something I am missing in my config that causes it?
- ***Is there a way to silence the warning***?

**Warning**

```
$ yarn test
yarn run v1.22.10
$ react-scripts test -- --config=jest.config.ts

  Invalid testPattern --config=jest.config.ts|--watch|--config|{"roots":["<rootDir>\\src"],"collectCoverageFrom":["src\\**\\*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}","!src\\
**\\*.d.ts"],"setupFiles":node_modules\\react-app-polyfill\\jsdom.js"],"setupF
ilesAfterEnv":[],"testMatch":["<rootDir>\\src\\**\\__tests__\\**\\*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}","<rootDir>\\src\\**\\*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],"testEnviron
ment":"jsdom","testRunner":"\node_modules\\jest-circus\\runner.js","transform":{"
^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$"\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\config\\jest\\cs
sTransform.js","^(?!.*\\.node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom\build\index.js supplied. Running all tests instead.
  Invalid testPattern --config=jest.config.ts|--watch|--config|{"roots":["<rootDir>\\src"],"collectCoverageFrom":["src\\**\\*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}","!src\\
**\\*.d.ts"],"setupFiles":node_modules\\react-app-polyfill\\jsdom.js"],"setupF
ilesAfterEnv":[],"testMatch":["<rootDir>\\src\\**\\__tests__\\**\\*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}","<rootDir>\\src\\**\\*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],"testEnviron
ment":"jsdom","testRunner":"\node_modules\\jest-circus\\runner.js","transform":{"
^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$"\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\config\\jest\\cs
sTransform.js","^(?!.*\\.node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom\build\index.js supplied. Running all tests instead.
```

**Jest config**

```js
// jest.config.ts

const jestConfig = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
    },
  },
  verbose: true,
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>/test/**/*(*.)+(test).+(tsx|ts)'],
  setupFiles: ['dotenv/config'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    '<rootDir>/test/setupTests.ts',
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'ts', 'tsx'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: 'target/coverage',
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.tsx',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^.+\\.(css|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '^.+\\.(png|svg|pdf|jpg|jpeg)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    '^@foo/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
};

export default jestConfig;
```

**Dependencies**

- jest@26.6.2
- react@17.0.2
- yarn@1.22.10

**Binaries**

- Node: 14.7.0
- Yarn: 1.22.10
- npm: 6.14.11

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `--` is specifically saying that everything following it is in fact a file pattern. So `--config=jest.config.ts` is not being interpreted as an option at all and the confusing error arises from the `react-scripts test` command trying to understand it as a file pattern. Options would have to come BEFORE the `--`

See https://www.baeldung.com/linux/double-dash-in-shell-commands

Comment: Thanks for the link. We aggree on the usage of the doubled dash. Turns out, no test iis found when I change the test pattern to these: react-scripts test  --config=jest.config.ts or react-scripts test  --config=jest.config.ts -- or  react-scripts test  --config=jest.config.ts or react-scripts test  --config jest.config.ts or react-scripts test -- --config jest.config.ts

Comment: Update: that message is actually printed because the internal jest config of CRA is being ovverriden by mine. All is well, nothing alarming .

Comment: @exaucae, so it's not possible to override jest config file with CRA boilerplate code without ejecting

Comment: @sagg1295, yes it is possible, to override jest config file. The extra thing is that each time you run your test you'll get the above error message  because CRA internals don't expect you to do so... But as of now, that should not matter: it doesn't prevent your code from running nor creates a side effect. It is just annoying.